# making an example of inheritance, well... bad

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm reading a book Object Oriented Design in Ruby and there is a part that shows `MountainBike` class as an example of bad inheritance practices. It is not shown exactly, but implied that the `Bicycle` class that the former inherits from is written the same way. So, the code we have is the following...

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :style, :size, :tape_color,
              :front_shock, :rear_shock

  def initialize(args)
    @style = args[:style]
    @size = args[:size]
    @tape_color = args[:tape_color]
    @front_shock = args[:front_shock]
    @rear_shock = args[:rear_shock]
  end

  def spares
    if style == :road
      { chain: '10-speed',
        tire_size: '23',
        tape_color: tape_color }
    else
      { chain: '10-speed',
        tire_size: '2.1',
        rear_shock: rear_shock }
    end
  end

end

class MountainBike < Bicycle
  attr_reader :front_shock, :rear_shock

  def initialize(args)
    @front_shock = args[:front_shock]
    @rear_shock = args[:rear_shock]
    super(args)
  end

  def spares
    super.merge(rear_shock: rear_shock)
  end
end

mountain_bike = MountainBike.new(
        size:        'S',
        front_shock: 'Manitou',
        rear_shock:  'Fox' )

puts mountain_bike.size
puts mountain_bike.spares
```

The output for `mountain_bike.spares` is supposed to be this scramble

```
{:tire_size => "23", :chain => "10-speed", :tape_color => nil, :front_shock => 'Manitou', :rear_shock => "Fox"}
```

But, what I get is

```
{:chain=>"10-speed", :tire_size=>"2.1", :rear_shock=>"Fox"}
```

which obviously doesn't prove the intended point. 
How can class Bicycle be re-written to match the "wrong" output?

Comment: Could you clarify which parts of the code (and output) are written in the book and can't be changed, and which parts you're trying to guess? I can't think of any reasonable answer in its current form.

Comment: the entire `MountainBike` class and the output that begins with `{:tire_size => "23"...` is what's given in this particular section. `Bicycle` class comes from earlier part, so not sure if it's supposed to have been rewritten to get that output.

Comment: I think it must be a totally different design then. There's no way it would output `:tire_size => "23"` without passing a style to the constructor.

Comment: Right! I found that odd as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sivanes, you're got the wrong `Bicycle` class.

In Practical-Object Oriented Design in Ruby, on page 115, when the `MountainBike` class above is introduced, it says:

> The following is a first attempt at a MountainBike subclass. This new
>   subclass is a direct descendent of the **original Bicycle class**.

The original `Bicycle` class is:

```ruby
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :tape_color

  def initialize(args)
    @size       = args[:size]
    @tape_color = args[:tape_color]
  end

  # every bike has the same defaults for
  # tire and chain size
  def spares
    { chain:        '10-speed',
      tire_size:    '23',
      tape_color:   tape_color}
  end

  # Many other methods...
end
```

Running the code with this version of `Bicycle` will give you the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong here.

Look at the code in `Bicycle` for method `spares`:

```
def spares
  if style == :road
    { chain: '10-speed',
      tire_size: '23',
      tape_color: tape_color }
  else
    { chain: '10-speed',
      tire_size: '2.1',
      rear_shock: rear_shock }
  end
end
```

Do you see an `if` condition: `if style == :road`? Right? Good, please make a note here.

Now, look at the method `spares` inside class `MountainBike` which is inherited from `Bicycle`:

```
def spares
  super.merge(rear_shock: rear_shock)
end
```

Do you see `super`? It will call parent's class method, in this case `spares` method. Since you are initializing the object of `MountainBike` class with this:

```
mountain_bike = MountainBike.new(size:        'S',
                                 front_shock: 'Manitou',
                                 rear_shock:  'Fox' ) # no style in argument!!
```

It is quite apparent that the condition we just noted above will fall in `else`, which will give:

```
{ chain: '10-speed',
  tire_size: '2.1',
  rear_shock: rear_shock }
```

and then merge:

```
{ chain: '10-speed',
  tire_size: '2.1',
  rear_shock: rear_shock }.merge(rear_shock: rear_shock)
```

and since `rear_shock`'s value is: `'Fox'`, the above code will be finally evaluated to:

```
{ chain: '10-speed', tire_size: '2.1', rear_shock: 'Fox' }
```

Isn't that what exactly you were expecting?

Note that `{a: 'b'}` is as same as writing `{:a => 'b'}`, it's just a syntax sugar.

So, my point is either the book you've read has some different code/approach to show the inheritance example or it has a miss-printed output. There's no way it can print:

```
{:tire_size => "23", :chain => "10-speed", :tape_color => nil, :front_shock => 'Manitou', :rear_shock => "Fox"}
```

Comment: yes, me and another user who commented the main post came to same conclusion regarding `else`, but you spelling everything out helps me as well. I emailed the author of the book, maybe she'll shed some light on this.